# Using Spring MVC 3.1+ WebApplicationInitializer to programmatically configure session-config and error-page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

[WebApplicationInitializer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) provides a way to programmatically represent a good portion of a standard web.xml file - the servlets, filters, listeners.

However I have not been able to figure out a good way to represent these elements(session-timeout, error-page) using WebApplicationInitializer, is it necessary to still maintain a web.xml for these elements?

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/uncaughtException</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resourceNotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I done a bit of research on this topic and found that for some of the configurations like sessionTimeOut and error pages you still need to have the web.xml.

Have look at this [Link](http://explodingjava.blogspot.in/2010/05/servlet-30-annotations.html)

Hope this helps you.
Cheers.

Comment: Thank @Japs, yes sounds like these will need to be done via web.xml file

Comment: Has the situation changed or we still need to have a `web.xml`?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Haven't tried it recently with latest spring version.

Comment: You can use `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method or `@ControllerAdvice` class for **error-page** configurations. For **session-config** add listener for session and use setMaxInactiveInterval() to specify time-out.

Comment: The `@ExceptionHandler` only works for errors you throw in your controllers. It does not work for SpringSecurity 401/403 or plain 404s.

Comment: The Servlet 4.0 API adds a `setSessionTimeout` method now

Answer (score 5):

Using spring-boot it's pretty easy.

I am sure it could be done without spring boot as well by extending [SpringServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html). It seems that is what it is specifically designed for.

> Servlet 3.0 ServletContainerInitializer designed to support code-based
>   configuration of the servlet container using Spring's
>   WebApplicationInitializer SPI as opposed to (or possibly in
>   combination with) the traditional web.xml-based approach.

Sample code (using SpringBootServletInitializer)

```
public class MyServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(8080);

        // configure error pages
        containerFactory.getErrorPages().add(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/errors/401"));

        // configure session timeout
        containerFactory.setSessionTimeout(20);

        return containerFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a @Bean annotation missing at the servletContainer() method.

Comment: This only works for an embedded tomcat. There it's easier to set `server.session-timeout=20` in `application.properties`

Comment: It's worth noting that the JavaDoc for SpringServletContainerInitializer explicitly says "This class is neither designed for extension nor intended to be extended. It should be considered an internal type". So I don't think it's correct to say that "It seems that is what it is specifically designed for." The quote you took from the JavaDoc is correct - the class does *support* the code-based configuration, but it does so by delegating to WebApplicationInitializer, not by providing an extension point itself.

Answer (score 4):

Actually `WebApplicationInitializer` doesn't provide it directly. But there is a way to set sessointimeout with java configuration.

You have to create a `HttpSessionListner` first :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        //here session will be invalidated by container within 30 mins 
        //if there isn't any activity by user
        se.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1800);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Session destroyed");
    }
}
```

After this just register this listener with your servlet context which will be available in `WebApplicationInitializer` under method `onStartup`

```
servletContext.addListener(SessionListener.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on BwithLove comment, you can define 404 error page using exception and controller method which is @ExceptionHandler:

1. Enable throwing **NoHandlerFoundException** in DispatcherServlet.
2. Use **@ControllerAdvice** and **@ExceptionHandler** in controller.

WebAppInitializer class:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(getContext());
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping("/");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("com.my.config");
    context.scan("com.my.controllers");
    return context;
}
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@ControllerAdvice
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String whenStart() {
        return "index";
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String requestHandlingNoHandlerFound(HttpServletRequest req, NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        return "error404";
    }
}
```

"error404" is a JSP file.

Answer (score 1):

In web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>3</session-timeout>
</session-config>-->
<listener>
    <listenerclass>

  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Listener Class

```
public class ProductBidRollBackListener implements HttpSessionListener {

 @Override
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

 }

 @Override
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
    HttpSession session=httpSessionEvent.getSession();
    WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());
    ProductService productService=(ProductService) context.getBean("productServiceImpl");
    Cart cart=(Cart)session.getAttribute("cart");
    if (cart!=null && cart.getCartItems()!=null && cart.getCartItems().size()>0){
        for (int i=0; i<cart.getCartItems().size();i++){
            CartItem cartItem=cart.getCartItems().get(i);
            if (cartItem.getProduct()!=null){
                Product product = productService.getProductById(cartItem.getProduct().getId(),"");
                int stock=product.getStock();
                product.setStock(stock+cartItem.getQuantity());
                product = productService.updateProduct(product);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```