# How to set session-timeout, error-pages programmatically without web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and have successfully setup a WebApplicationInitializer (using Tomcat's ServletContainerInitializer), without any web.xml file.  Adding filters (like Spring Security) and servlets (like Dispatcher) is no problem, and they work fine.  I can also set init-params if I need to do so.

What I can't figure out is how to set up some of the special tags that normally exist in the web.xml.  For example, I would like to set up a custom 403 error page.  Usually I would do this in web.xml with:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/accessDenied.html</location>
</error-page>
```

But I can't figure out how to do this inside the WebApplicationInitializer (which has access to the ServletContext).

I have the same problem with session-timeout and welcome-files.  I've been searching for about two days, but still haven't seen this done programmatically.  Again the goal is to completely remove the web.xml file and use the initializer class instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is possible through WebApplicationInitializer, you will have to stick to web.xml for specifically this configuration along with some others listed with this question - [Using Spring MVC 3.1+ WebApplicationInitializer to programmatically configure session-config and error-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813993/using-spring-mvc-3-1-webapplicationinitializer-to-programatically-configure-ses)

Comment: Thanks.  That does appear to be the case, based on the link in your answer.  Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

```
StandardEngine standardEngine = (StandardEngine)MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(0).getAttribute(new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Engine"), "managedResource");

// This is totally irresponsible and will only work if this webapp is running on the default host
StandardContext standardContext = (StandardContext)standardEngine.findChild(standardEngine.getDefaultHost()).findChild(servletContext.getContextPath());

ErrorPage errorPage404 = new ErrorPage();
errorPage404.setErrorCode(404);
errorPage404.setLocation("/404");
standardContext.addErrorPage(errorPage404);
```

Comment: Which .jar is needed at compile time to access `org.apache.catalina.*` classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use somethink like this:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "ErrorPageFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class ErrorPageFilter extends BaseHttpFilter {

private GlobalErrorHandler globalErrorHandler;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    globalErrorHandler = BeansUtil.getBean(filterConfig.getServletContext(), GlobalErrorHandler.class);
}

@Override
protected void doHttpFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, new ErrorPageHttpServletResponseWrapper(request, response));
}

private class ErrorPageHttpServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public ErrorPageHttpServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
        globalErrorHandler.handleError(sc, request, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
        sendError(sc);
    }
}
}

public interface GlobalErrorHandler {

void handleError(int responseCode, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletRequest) throws IOException;

void addHandler(int responseCode, String handlerDescription);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a really solution to this issue.

Comment: What is `BeansUtil` in this example? How does it extract your own invented `GlobalErrorHandler` from a `ServletContext` object?

Comment: Yes, it is a small util for getting beans from ServletContext by class.

Answer (score 0):

For page-error, see this answer: [How to make a filter to detect if the user requested a page that is not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324176/how-to-make-a-filter-to-detect-if-the-user-requested-a-page-that-is-not-found)

> 1. Make a Filter
> 2. Use HttpServletResponseWrapper and override the sendError() and setStatus()
> 3. Pass the wrapped response through chain.doFilter(req, wrapper)
> 4. If you get a sendError() in your wrapper, see if it's a 404.
> 5. Take appropriate response.