# How to register listener in Spring without deployment descriptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-listeners

I'm slowly stepping in Java world through Spring Framework (4.1.0) and need your help with Listeners.

I have created application without deployment descriptor, all Spring related configuration is managed in `@Configuration` annotated classes. Everything is working but I can't find a way to register listeners.

**Question**: How I can register listeners in Spring (4.1.0) based on Java `@Configuration` annotated classed ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30908951/1901067

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do that with the help of the [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) class. `@Configuration` is for Spring configurations, not for the deployment descriptor.

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        container.addListener(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

You can find more explanations here: [How to use Spring's WebApplicationInitializer](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/how-to-use-springs-webapplicationinitializer/).

Comment: thanks for explanation on this subject. In my app I'm using class inherited from `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` as initializer thus I can register listener there from what I checked.

Comment: Yes, AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: For my SpringBoot application, i didn't have to use this addListener approach, infact when i put this code, it was not getting executed. Any clue on why is that ?