# How to start DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have written a Spring application for consuming messages using MDP which uses DefaultMessageListnerContainer. I wrote a messageListner and passed it to the property of messageListener to DMLC.
My Spring configuration is below

```
<!-- ConnectionFactory Definition -->
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
</bean> 

<!-- Message Receiver Definition -->
<bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.practice.MessageReceiver.MyMessageConsumer">
</bean>
<bean id="actualQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="ActualQueue" />
</bean>
<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="actualQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
</bean>
```

I want to know how to start this DMLC? I deployed it in Jboss 6.1. But its not consuming messages. I am missing something which I am not able to get by searching for an answer.

Comment: If you have initialized the DMLC with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext normally it auto starts. Check the logs maybe the amqConnectionFactory is not well configured ?

Comment: MyMessageConsumer implements javax.jms.MessageListener ?

Comment: Thanks Hassen. I am able to see the MyMessageListener listening to messages when I run this as a standalone application. But I am looking for the solution on how it will be invoked when deployed in Jboss on server start up.

Comment: You need a WebApplicationInitializer to start the  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext see that  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25822418/6506229