# Spring MVC custom message for HTTP 400

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have several SprigMVC methods like this below, returning either a ModelAndView or a Responsebody. When users makes a request to these urls missing the required parameters they naturally get the message **"Required String parameter 'id' is not present"**.

From security perspective I want to **hide this detailed description messages** from users. So a hacker don't easily know the missing parameters and will get a 400 error without any description. Is this possible via a spring configuration/Spring Security or I have to manually refactor all my methods to return a custom message somehow.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getReponse(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true)) {

    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getStatus(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id) {

    return "string";
}
```

Comment: So bypassing that error will also help right?

Comment: @Rehman not sure what you mean by bypass but probably

Comment: Now its clear after editing your question. I was thinking about `required=false`. But you want 400

Comment: can you show your `web.xml`? particularly the `error-page` part, if you have it configured (some examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml)

Comment: You can use @ExceptionHandler. Here is a an example how to use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356549/handle-error-404-with-spring-controller

Comment: @Michal M tnx looks like web.xml solution works. I have to see what is the best approach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you actually need is a global handler for [MissingServletRequestParameterException](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MissingServletRequestParameterException.html), which is thrown by Spring when a request parameter is missing. The easiest way to tackle this problem is to use [ControllerAdvice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-controlleradvice-classes) that will handle it for all your controllers.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException;

@ControllerAdvice
class MissingServletRequestParameterExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleMissingParameter() {
        return "Your custom result";
    }
}
```

If you want to hide the missing parameter message only for a particular controller, just move `handleMissingParameter` method to this controller without creating the ControllerAdvice.

Comment: tnx. does this approach has any advantage over using <error-page> in my web.xml? I just tried and I could show my own custom error page for all 400 errors

Comment: If you just want to display a simple error page then no, <error-page> is sufficient. But you can use this handler to log such a situation and since you wrote about attacks that information may be interesting for you.

Comment: yes indeed for logging! tnx but its not clear how can I use it for a single controller method? And is there a way to get the HttpRequest object for detailed logging

Comment: `@ExceptionHandler` works on the class level. If you put it inside a controller class, it handles specified exception for all methods inside this class. Unfortunately, it's not possible to choose only a selected method. You need some custom solution, e.g., pass a request to the handler method and verify whether for that URL you should execute the handler or re-throw the exception.

Answer (score 4):

I personally upvoted Daniel Olszewski's answer because it's hip, nice, concise and readable, although in a customer-facing, publicly available site (when you go beyond the fast prototyping with Spring Boot phase and need to be perfectly sure that *nothing* gets through) one may want to use it together with the plain-old `error-page` in web.xml approach (some examples here: [Handle error 404 with Spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356549/handle-error-404-with-spring-controller)).

It may not be fun (I, personally, despise anything XML related beyond explainability), but (unless you're not using web.xml at all in favor of WebApplicationInitializer), web.xml is *almost* the lowest layer in a web app and no error page (no matter the exception or URL mapping) will get through it, just remember to map all the HTTP status codes (i.e. have one default `error-page` element without the child `error-code` element).

The solution for WebApplicationInitializer is analogous, some xamples here: [Using Spring MVC 3.1+ WebApplicationInitializer to programmatically configure session-config and error-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813993/using-spring-mvc-3-1-webapplicationinitializer-to-programatically-configure-ses).

*The lowest* layer approach would be to set the error page contener-wide, e.g. for Tomcat: http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/c581.html.